# Delete/Add a specific Element(int) in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, addition, element

This subclass should be able to let the user choose a specific employee ID, type it into the command line and choose to either add it to the array list, delete it from the array list or simply request to see more information about the specific employee ID. I've tried so many things with no luck at all.

```
package WorkIDServerStorage;

public class EmployeeList{
    private Employee[] theEmployee;
    private int arrayEmployee;

    public EmployeeList(){
        theEmployee = new Employee[100];
        arrayEmployee = 0;
    }

    public EmployeeList(int arraySize){
        theEmployee = new Employee[arraySize];
        arrayEmployee = 0;
    }

    public void setTheEmployee(Employee[] inputTheEmployee){
        theEmployee = inputTheEmployee;
    }

    public void setArrayEmployee(int inputArrayEmployee){
        arrayEmployee = inputArrayEmployee;
    }

    public Employee[] getTheEmployee(){
        return theEmployee;
    }

    public int getArrayEmployee(){
        return arrayEmployee;
    }

    public Employee addEmployeeID(Employee employeeAdd){
        return theEmployee[arrayEmployee++] = employeeAdd;
    }

    public Employee deleteEmployeeID(int employeeDelete){
         //Delete an employee record with a 
         //specified record number from the array
    }

    public Employee readEmployeeInfo(int employeeRead){
        //Read the employee data for a specified record number 
        //From the array and display this data to the screen
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int x = 0; x < arrayEmployee; x++){
            sb.append(theEmployee[x].toString()).append("\n");
        }return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What isn't working?

Comment: Having trouble coming up with a way to allow the user to delete and read a specific employee ID from the array list... If that makes any sense

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are fixed length data structures. They are much like a multi-storied building. You can't take a floor out from the middle of the building and expect it to stand.

ArrayList (as others have pointed out), are dynamic structures, much like a train. You can take out compartments as you wish, you can reconfigure it.

I would in fact recommend **NOT** using a List at all, but a Map that maps an ID to an employee record. Let us say you have the following employees in a list -

1. Alice
2. Bob
3. John
4. Ruth

If you delete "Bob" the ID's for John and Ruth are going to change. Not a good practice. If you use a Map instead, everyone can keep their assigned ID's and you just add to the map by incrementing the keys (or IDs).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For being able to dynamically adding or removing from an array, you should use **List**, or **ArrayList**. Typical arrays don't provide delete or add at runtime, since they are fixed-size and if you want to control the procedure by handling the indices or other tricks, you'll probably end up in a messy and hard to maintain code.
On the other hand, Lists in java are dynamically sized and provide **add(),** **remove()**, **get()** and other convenient methods, which in my opinion best suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an ArrayList in order to dynamically add and remove entries in your array.

Make your theEmployee array into an ArrayList by doing:

```
ArrayList<Employee> theEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

You can add and remove by doing:

```
public boolean addEmployeeID(Employee employeeAdd){
    return theEmployee.add(employeeAdd);
}

public Employee deleteEmployeeID(int employeeDelete){
     return theEmployee.remove(employeeDelete)
}
```

I changed the return type of addEmployeeID to boolean because an ArrayList returns a boolean when you add an object.

For remove, int employeeDelete would be the index of the object in the array. When you remove an object, all the remaining objects get shifted to the left. So if you have an array [1,2,3] and you remove 2, it would become [1,3]. The indexes are moved.

You could also remove an object so this should work:

```
public boolean deleteEmployeeID(Employee employeeDelete){
     return theEmployee.remove(employeeDelete)
}
```

Where employeeDelete is an Employee and the function returns a boolean.